# Confusing function declaration syntax

Tags: flutter, dart

In the [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets/versions/1.0.1-nullsafety.0) package, the following declaration appears:

```dart
final PlatformAppBar Function(BuildContext context, int index)? appBarBuilder;
```

I'm sorry for the beginner question, but I am confused by this syntax.  I understand the `final` and the name of the instance is `appBarBuilder`.

I am used to seeing a declaration like:

```dart
final Classname? classInstance;
```

Where in this declaration, the `classInstance` can also be `null`.
But it seems to see this declaration has two types: `PlatformAppBar` and `Function(BuildContext context, int index)?`. I don't think something can have two different types, so what is going on here?

My final goal is to pass a `null` function.

Here is how I am using it.  Some of the pages need an app bar and others do not, which is why I am trying to return a null for some pages.

```dart
return PlatformTabScaffold(
  appBarBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 1) return SearchPage.appBar(context);
    if (index == 3) return CalculatorPage.appBar(context);
    return null;  // Gives error The return type 'Null' isn't a 'PlatformAppBar', as required by the closure's context.
  },
  // Other parameters...
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
final PlatformAppBar Function(BuildContext context, int index)? appBarBuilder;
```

declares a variable named `appBarBuilder` of type:

```dart
PlatformAppBar Function(BuildContext context, int index)?
```

`appBarBuilder` therefore either is `null` or is a function that takes arguments of type `BuildContext` and `int` and that returns a `PlatformAppBar`.

> Here is how I am using it. Some of the pages need an app bar and others do not, which is why I am trying to return a null for some pages.
>
> ```dart
> return PlatformTabScaffold(
>   appBarBuilder: (context, index) {
>     if (index == 1) return SearchPage.appBar(context);
>     if (index == 3) return CalculatorPage.appBar(context);
>     return null;  // Gives error The return type 'Null' isn't a 'PlatformAppBar', as required by the closure's context.
>   },
>   // Other parameters...
> );
> ```

Your code is *not* passing `null` to `appBarBuilder`.  You are passing an anonymous function that returns `null` when invoked.  Consider:

```dart
int Function()? f = null;
int? Function()? g = () => null;

print(f == null); // Prints: true
print(g == null); // Prints: false

print(g() == null); // Prints: true
f(); // Throws a runtime exception.
```

In your case, it does not seem to me that you actually want `appBarBuilder` itself to be `null`; you instead want invoking it to conditionally do nothing based on `index`.

I'm not familiar with `package:flutter_platform_widgets`, but I suspect that there might not be a way to do what you want.  You probably should contact the package author and ask if there's a preferred way to make the callback do nothing, and if not, perhaps change the declaration of `appBarBuilder` to `PlatformAppBar? Function(BuildContext context, int index)?` instead so that it allows a `null` return value.

Comment: So if I am passing the appBarBuilder as an argument, I expect I should be able to pass a `null` value.  But if I pass `null`, I get the error `The return type 'Null' isn't a 'PlatformAppBar', as required by the closure's context.`  If I try to pass `() => null` I get the error `The return type 'Null Function()' isn't a 'PlatformAppBar', as required by the closure's context.`. How can I pass a null?

Comment: You should be able to set `appBarBuilder` to `null`.  I'd have to see your exact code to tell what you're doing wrong, but assuming you're trying to construct a `PlatformTabScaffold`, it should be just: `PlatformTabScaffold(appBarBuilder: null, ...)`.  Or, since `appBarBuilder` is an optional argument to `PlatformTabScaffold`'s constructor, just omit it.

Comment: Yes, I am using it with a `PlatformTabScaffold `.  I've posted my code in my question above so you can see how it is used.  I get an error when I set it to null as you suggest... not sure why.

Comment: @jon Your code is *not* passing `null` for `appBarBuilder`.  You're passing an anonymous function.  Your function ends with `return null`, but the `appBarBuilder` is declared to return a `PlatformAppBar` (which is *not* nullable, so returning `null` is not legal).

Comment: I have tried it both ways... passing an anonymous function and passing null as I updated above.

Comment: Please show your code where you pass `null` for `appBarBuilder` and show what error you get.  That is not the code that you've shown.

Comment: I guess I am confused because I thought that was what I had done.  Can you suggest code that will pass `null` for `appBarBuilder`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229978/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-jon).